# she has a pretty face vs she has the pretty face

Tags: grammar

My student asked me why we say "she has **a** pretty face" when describing someone. Is it possible to say "she has **the** pretty face" (we obviously have only one face)? And if not, how can we explain it? Can we apply the rule "*The indefinite article is used with singular countable nouns
to refer to a person or a thing that you are mentioning for the first time*"?

Comment: She has the pretty face would imply that there is only one pretty face in the universe and she has it.

Answer (score 1):

To say

> she has the pretty face

would suggest that there is only one face, or only one pretty face. In fact there are many possible faces. So one says:

> she has a pretty face

which indicates that there are many possible pretty faces, and she has one of them.

In general when describing aspects of a person, one says in standard English

> S/he has a/an {adjective} {noun}

and not a sentence using a definite article.